# Border-left-width returns NaN in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, nan, border-box

I'm busy writing a small snippet of code that should allow cross-browser usage of the border-box box model. So far the basic functionality works fine, but I can't get the margin to work. It should adapt to the space that's available, but console returns a NaN and I have no idea where it comes from.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/PD7tk/11/) is a fiddle.

The console.log doesn't even log anything and I don't know why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `parseInt($(this).css("border-left-width"), 10)`, the code doesn't reach the `console.log` because of the string multiplication before of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many parts of your fiddle you have this pattern:

```
($(this).css("border-left-width") * 2).replace("px", "")
```

You're trying to erase the `px` **after** executing a multiplication which results in a syntax error. It should be either

```
($(this).css("border-left-width").replace("px", "") * 2)
```

Which works through auto type conversion or

```
(parseInt($(this).css("border-left-width"), 10) * 2)
```

Which parses the string as an integer, removing the trailing `px`:

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point. `parseInt` truncates
>   numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/PD7tk/12/)

[`parseInt` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

Because this:

```
  $(this).css("padding-left")
```

and

```
$(this).css("border-left-width")
```

returns a string containing "px", which you try to multiply with 2, resulting in NaN. You can solve this problem by parsing the resulting strings to floats before multiplying, like this:

```
(parseFloat($(this).css("padding-left")) * 2 )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Technically, it's the "px" in the string that results in the NaN, and the parseFloat just ignores that.

Comment: Yes, it parses all numbers until it hits a non numerical char. But it still solves the problem.