# How come I cant add code after changing the css of button with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
function test() {
 //allows code here 
$("#h1").css("background-color", "yellow").replace("px", "") * 2;
 //denys all code here
}
```

Below is what im trying to archieve:

```
function test() {
$("#h1").css("background-color", "yellow").replace("px", "") * 2;
$("#h2").css("background-color", "black").replace("px", "") * 2;
}
```

Any help or input about how to deal with this is highly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: got some help from here [Border-left-width returns NaN in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232056/border-left-width-returns-nan-in-jquery) to create my code

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: code to run after the first jquery css change within the same function

Comment: You are calling replace on $("h1"). jQuery is about chaining. Your code contains an error.
What property are you trying to multiply by 2?

Comment: Why are you multiplying the entire line by 2? What you trying to have happen? It's not very clear based on what you have tried here what you are expecting as your end result.

Comment: @mattias - You might want to go over your code again... The statement does not make sense... Perhaps you are missing a call to `.attr('property')` before the replace.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's being asked here. Maybe you could try to ask again.

Comment: No idea what you are attempting here, maybe clearly explain what the end result is suppose to be because $("#h1").css("background-color", "yellow").replace("px", "") * 2; is not valid, nor does it make sense.

Comment: The jquery works and changes the first "$("#h1").css("background-color", "yellow").replace("px", "") * 2;" but denys all code that i run under it. I've searched and added this replace(px) thing because otherwise the button text becomes NaN for some reason

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232056/border-left-width-returns-nan-in-jquery is where i got it

Comment: it's NaN because "$("#h1").css("background-color", "yellow").replace("px", "")" is not a number, don't know why you are multiplying it by 2

Comment: @mattias - See how you question is unclear... We don't know anything about a button, you didn't specify what you are trying to do... The reason for you code stop working from this line on, is because it throws an error and stops the JS execution.

Comment: After seeing that other stack overflow question. Just remove replace("px", "") * 2.

Comment: @mattias The example you linked is using the `border-left-width` css property ... you are trying to do math on a `background-color`. Can you tell me what 2 * yellow is? lol

Comment: Ye i had this issue with NaN and then changed as the answer in the other stackoverflow question and it started working. i guess it had me confused, anyhow works now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  $("#h1").css("background-color", "yellow").replace("px", "") * 2;
  $("#h2").css("background-color", "black").replace("px", "") * 2;
```

to

```
$("#h1").css("background-color", "yellow");
$("#h2").css("background-color", "black");
```

You are replacing the background color already with .css("background-color", "yellow") . Unless there is some specific reason you are doing the replace and multiply (which will not even work with "background-color", "yellow") just remove it.

Comment: Ye thanks, i had it like that earlier but got an issue with button text becoming == NaN for some reason which confused me, anyhow works now, cheers

Comment: @mattias It's Nan because the .replace("px", "") * 2; are completely irrelevant to what you are tying to do and erroring. If you really want to dig into it - the NaN is refering to the * 2 which is trying to multiply against the previous part of the function which is.. well ... not a number :P.

Answer (score 1):

let me explain a couple things:

1 - When you execute this code: `$("#h1").css("background-color", "yellow")` it will return an array-like or jquery DOM object

2 - You cannot replace the string `"px"` with a `""` there because it is not a string, so you get an `Uncaught Exception` and code execution stops there. Actually it does not even get multiplied by `2` cause it's stoped already

So that's why you cannot se execution after the first line

**EDIT:** In order to achieve your multiplication or whatever operation you need you should retrieve the NUMERIC attribute you need with `.attr()` or `.css()` like this:

```
$("#h1").css("height").replace("px","")
```

that will return a string with the numeric value without the `px` prefix, and now you can do whatever you need with the value:

```
$("#h1").css("height", parseInt($("#h1").css("height").replace("px",""),10)*2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a TypeError for calling the function `replace` on a jQuery object.
`replace` should be called on a string.